# Android- Animator with Button

Tags: android

```
alpha = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.5f);
alpha.setFillAfter(true); 
Button_A.setAnimation(alpha);
```

**OnCreate is OK ! But...**

```
 Button_B.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                            alpha = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.5f);
                            alpha.setFillAfter(true); 
                            Button_A.setAnimation(alpha);


        }
    });
```

**It's didn't work !**

Please help me ! Sorry .My english not best.

Comment: Is `alpha.start();` missing?

Comment: Sorry ! but . it's didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to give the setduration after instantiate the animation object.
try this

```
Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
animation.setDuration(1000);
```

refer this [link](http://tsicilian.wordpress.com/2012/04/26/android-special-effects-alpha-animation/)

Comment: Plus: Button_A.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); << this is OK. Thanks for Help !

Comment: if your Button_A hide the Button_B then you need to put View.GONE to make it remove.